# execve from a Mac OS X launchd daemon

Tags: c++, macos, daemon, launchd, execve

Is it possible to use [execve](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/execve.2.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/2/execve) from a launchd daemon? My process that I would like to make into a daemon launches several child processes using fork() followed by execve, but the [documentation for creating launchd daemons](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Articles/LaunchOnDemandDaemons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001762-104302) states that "calling fork followed by exec" is not ok. Does this mean that I cannot create child processes from a daemon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, you can fork and exec just fine. The critical point is this one: *"You must not fork your process and have the parent process exit."* Thing is, launchd "watches over" your service. If your service exits, it gets restarted. That means it may not daemonize, either (with daemonize I mean the classical *spawn a new process, create a new process group, exit parent process, subprocess lives on* scheme).

I guess you should make sure to kill/quit your subprocesses before you exit the main process, just to not litter the environment.

Comment: I was porting a cross-platform application and came across this problem. The executable specified in the plist was starting multiple time because the standard fork,exec, exit the parent was used so I ended up with an infinite number of instances of that executable that would even freeze or crash the OS if not stopped.